# How do I find out how much of my RAM is being used by the GPU?

Tags: windows-7, memory, gpu

I just started Call of Duty and noticed that it took a moderate ~1.2 GiB of RAM.
Then looked at the system information and noticed that I only had ~1 GiB out of my 6 GiB left.

The only explanation I can think of is that my GPU (NVIDIA Geforce 330M) is using the rest.

Is this even the explanation? And if so, how can I find out how much RAM my GPU is actually using?

#### Edit:

Yes, the card **does** have shared memory, because my laptop specifications say:

> Processor: NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 330M GPU with Total
> Available Graphics Memory of 2263MB (max.)
> Video RAM: 512MB dedicated video RAM

And yes, I was playing CoD with the *highest* texture quality settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using VERY high graphics settings, you may find that it uses more than what your GPU has, and then begins using RAM from the system. You can use [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) to see how much is being used. It does appear though that card only has 256mb of RAM.

Here's a little picture of all the information you can view, I took it while idling.

[image: Sensor]

Comment: That only occures if his chip supports the [shared memory archetecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Memory_Architecture). Which it does not. http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-330M.22437.0.html

Comment: @Simon: Thanks a lot, I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

No its not, as the GPU uses its own RAM. I can't tell without looking at all of your running processes, but I guess those add to the missing 4GB.

Comment: But I believe this card also uses shared memory.

Comment: Shared memory has nothing to do with the RAM for the rest of the computer. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) under advantages. And anyway, its really really tiny (48KB).

Comment: Btw, this card does not used shared memory: http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-330M.22437.0.html

Comment: Ah. Sorry; I was jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @emb1995: No, you weren't -- at least, not according to my laptop specifications PDF. I think that link is either wrong, or doesn't apply to every instance of the card. @soandos